# Optimized Infragistics Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, infragistics

Recently we have encounter this issue about exporting reports to excel file using infragistics library.

Our report table contains more or less 1.26 million records as of now. We are trying to create an excel(2007) file for this, so approximately this will be 2 worksheets because only about 1million rows is supported by excel 2007 per sheet.

We have no problem during the creation of worksheets and during the filling of data into the worksheet, memory is manageable at this point.

**Our problem is when writing the excel data into the stream(file, memory).
The memory consumption is just too high and when it reaches 1.8GB it will no longer continue.**

*P.S. This is a summary report, the client wants this in a single excel file.*

**Your recommendations are much appreciated!!!**

Below is the code that i have pulled out from the actual source but i have replaced the data retrieval part and instead use a dummy data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Infragistics.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool tip = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xls = Workbook.MaxExcelRowCount;
            var xlsx =Workbook.MaxExcel2007RowCount;

            var wb = new Workbook(WorkbookFormat.Excel2007, WorkbookPaletteMode.StandardPalette);
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            var sheetCtr = 1;

            var limit = 1256898;
            var rr = 0;
            for (var row = 0; row < limit; row++)
            {
                if (rr >= xlsx - 1)
                {
                    //create new worksheet if row exceeded the limit
                    ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet" + sheetCtr.ToString());
                    rr = 0;
                    ClearMemory();
                }
                for (var col = 0; col < 10; col++)
                {
                    ws.Rows[rr].Cells[col].Value = string.Format("data{0}-{1}", row, col);
                }
                Console.Write("Row=");
                Console.Write(row.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
                rr++;
            }


            Console.Write("Saving worksheet...");

            //this part uses too much memory
            wb.Save("wb2.xlsx");

            Console.WriteLine("Workbook saved.");

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void ClearMemory()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                if (tip == true)
                {
                    proc.MaxWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)proc.MaxWorkingSet - 1);
                    proc.MinWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)proc.MinWorkingSet - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    proc.MaxWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)proc.MaxWorkingSet + 1);
                    proc.MinWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)proc.MinWorkingSet + 1);
                }
                tip = !tip;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to save an extremely large amount of unique strings here: 12,568,980, each of which holds about 42 bytes in memory, which is 527,897,160 bytes, just for the strings. Then you have the memory to store the strings: roughly 300 bytes per block of 32 cells with values on a row, which is another 377,069,400 bytes for the cells. That's already 900MB, and you still have to add in the memory for rows and other excel objects and some memory to do the actual save. You can try submitting this to IG to see if they can reduce the memory usage, but you might not get much of an improvement.

Comment: thanks mike, i will try to post this in their forum site